# Thousands and Decimal Separators in Jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

I need help on how to make it working this [jQuery Plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/z2qps/1/) with "." as thousand separators and "," as decimal separator. My Jquery knowledge is not enough to do that, i have tried to see other examples to understand how to implement, but i have not found them a part from [that](http://jsbin.com/ehuzes/5/edit) which is not exactly my case because it's based on click but at least has thousands and decimal Separators.

I would be glad if you can edit this [Jquery Plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/z2qps/1/) or send me some examples to understand how to do it.

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Allan/z2qps/6/? Math.ceil(x) will also round a number upward to it's nearest integer.

Comment: Yes exactly , but i want to make it working when i digit the number with commas and point, like http://jsfiddle.net/z2qps/7/, see the case inside the <div id="valorliquidativo">

Answer (score 0):

We could code it for you, but that is not what this site is for. If you need us to do this, hire us :-)

Now I'll point you in the right direction, so that you can achieve this yourself.

For some basic JavaScript & jQuery learing, try out [codecademy.com](http://www.codecademy.com). It will teach you about the basics and you will be able to learn some stuff. It is a really great site in my opinion and you can choose the subject yourself, from basic HTML to Advanced JavaScript.

To make this add-on, you'll need some knowledge about Math in Javascript, Mozilla does have a very nice site for information about this right [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math). You will need some basic skills with [jQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Some [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and the javascript [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

There is a addon [here](https://github.com/alonzzzo/cashRegister/blob/master/jquery.cashRegister.js) that does almost what you want. Try it out look at what it does, but try to code it yourself, you will learn a great deal.

The seperators part is already in the other addon you linked too. But this one is written using mooTools and not jQuery. You will need to understand these two functions.

```
addSeparators: function(number)
  {
    var parts = number.toString().split(this.options.decimalSeparator);

    var dollars = parts[0];
    if (parts[1]) { var cents = parts[1]; }

    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

    while (rgx.test(dollars)) {
        dollars = dollars.replace(rgx, '$1' + this.options.thousandsSeparator + '$2');
    }

    var output = dollars;

    if (this.options.precision > 0) {
      if (cents) {
        output += this.options.decimalSeparator + cents;
      } else {
        output += '0' * this.options.precision;
      }
    }

    return output;
  },

  stripSeparators: function(string) {
    var result = string.replace(this.options.decimalSeparator, '.');
    var pattern = new RegExp(this.options.thousandsSeparator, 'g');
    var matches = result.match(pattern)

    if (matches) {
      matches.each(function() {
        result = string.replace(pattern, '');
      });
    }

    return result;
  }
```

I hope this helps you, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, i am also trying out the addon you linked but i am having some issues, it's not working...

Comment: What is the problem, can you explain it? Do you get any errors?

Comment: That plugin does not work, i am going to write down the script on my own , looking this example http://jsbin.com/ehuzes/5/edit, i basically need to get the same not onclick but automatically, just when the page loads